# iPhone only app crashes on iPad only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, crash

I have an iPhone only app that crashes when starting up on an iPad. The response for the crash is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'.

Below is the full log of what happens. Any idea of what is going wrong here?

```
Filtered syslog:
2015-06-30 00:17:02.257 Rap Ready[228]:  assertion failed: 12F69: libxpc.dylib + 71768 [B870B51D-AA85-3686-A7D9-ACD48C5FE153]: 0x7d
2015-06-30 00:17:02.422 Rap Ready[228]:  [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
2015-06-30 00:17:02.524 Rap Ready[228]:  RKDOThisWeekTableViewController viewDidLoad
2015-06-30 00:17:02.527 Rap Ready[228]:  hud: (null)
2015-06-30 00:17:02.533 Rap Ready[228]:  requesting movies with category: this_week
2015-06-30 00:17:02.569 Rap Ready[228]:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1826f02d8 0x193c700e4 0x1826f0218 0x18357c6f0 0x1000ea3b8 0x1835f1db8 0x1944a3dc8 0x1944a3d24 0x1944a0ef8)
```

Comment: Why do you want to run iPhone only app on iPad ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia Anyone can run iPhone-only apps on an iPad.

Comment: Update your question with the code that causes the exception.

Comment: How do I find the 'uncaught exception' in the code?